# How to use iPhone method -(CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, cllocation

I am a new iPhone developer learning Objective-C, and am trying to dynamically calculate the distances between the users latitude/longitude coordinates, with latitude/longitude coordinates in a SQLite table.  I know that we can use CLLocations method:

```
(CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

to do this, but I'm not sure how to use it given the data that I have.  How does one use the above method using pairs of latitude/longitude coordinates, considering the above method only deals with location objects of type CLLocation?  Can anyone give me a simple example of how to use this method using two pairs of latitude/longitude coordinates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create `CLLocation` objects from your data:

```
// Assumption: lat1, lon1 and lat2, lon2 are double values containing the coordinates
CLLocation *firstLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lon1] autorelease];
CLLocation *secondLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:lon2] autorelease];
CLLocationDistance distance = [secondLocation distanceFromLocation:firstLocation];
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply!

Comment: It should be CLLocation *firstLocation and so on. They should be pointers